# открывающийся блок jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

есть скрипт блока который окрывается и закрывается, нужно сделать чтобы он изначально был закрытым но только страница загрузится сразу блок открывался

```js
function close(input) {

}
$(function() {
  $("#closea").click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass("closea")) {
      $(this).removeClass("closea");
      $("#closeimg").attr("src", "https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/google-material-design-icons/48/ic_keyboard_arrow_up_48px-512.png");
    } else {
      $(this).addClass("closea");
      $("#closeimg").attr("src", "https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/google-material-design-icons/48/ic_keyboard_arrow_down_48px-128.png");
    }
    $("#closediv").slideToggle("slow");
  });
});
```

```css
.close{
 text-align: ;
 position: fixed;
 bottom: 0px;
 right: 0px;
 width: 40%;
 background: rgb(80, 80, 80);
} 

.close:hover{
 
}

#closediv{
 
}

#closediv:hover{
 
}

#closea{
 background: rgba(80, 80, 80, 0.7) !important;
 cursor: pointer;
 text-align: center;
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='close'>

<div>
<a id='closea' onclick="close(this)" class="closea">
  <img id='closeimg' src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/google-material-design-icons/48/ic_keyboard_arrow_down_48px-128.png" style="width:30px">
</a>
</div>
<div id='closediv'>
content content content content content content content content content content content content content content 
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){}) - скрипт будет выполнятся когда страница загружена

Comment: @DmitriyKondratiuk можете помочь? я сделал так как вы сказали но у меня призагрузке страницы блок закрывается

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(function() {
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#closea").click(); // иметируем нажатие на бок
    $("#closediv").fadeIn(); // показываем блок с контентом
  });
});
$(function() {
  $("#closea").click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass("closea")) {
      $(this).removeClass("closea");
      $("#closeimg").attr("src", "https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/google-material-design-icons/48/ic_keyboard_arrow_up_48px-512.png");
    } else {
      $(this).addClass("closea");
      $("#closeimg").attr("src", "https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/google-material-design-icons/48/ic_keyboard_arrow_down_48px-128.png");
    }
    $("#closediv").slideToggle("slow");
  });
});
```

```css
.close{
 text-align: ;
 position: fixed;
 bottom: 0px;
 right: 0px;
 width: 40%;
 background: rgb(80, 80, 80);
} 

#closea{
 background: rgba(80, 80, 80, 0.7) !important;
 cursor: pointer;
 text-align: center;
 display: block;
}

#closediv {
 display: none; /* делаем блок с контетном невидимым */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='close'>

<div>
<a id='closea' onclick="close(this)" >
  <img id='closeimg' src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/google-material-design-icons/48/ic_keyboard_arrow_down_48px-128.png" style="width:30px">
</a>
</div>
<div id='closediv'>
content content content content content content content content content content content content content content 
</div>
</div>
```